# Compare and Edit Branches in Git with a Mergetool

Tags: git, diff, branch, beyondcompare, difftool

I have 2 branches that I can compare/diff using my difftool (Beyond Compare).
However, the files used for the diff are temporary copies and not the actual files from the current branch.
This means that if I want to make a change to an existing file, I cannot do it via the difftool. I would need to make a copy of the files of one branch, checkout the other branch and use a regular diff between the actual files.

Is there a way to get the difftool to use the actual files of the current branch (at least on one side)?

**UPDATE and SOLUTION**:

The command I used was `git difftool branch1 branch2`.
This diffs 2 branches regardless of the current branch.

The command `git difftool branch` works as desired, with one "side" as the currently checked-out branch.

Comment: How are you running difftool? When I run it (using meld), I get one copy in my workspace and one in /tmp/.

Comment: I ran `git difftool branch1 branch2`.
This was the problem!
When I now ran `git difftool branch1` it all worked as expected, with one "side" was the current branch.

Comment: After a long sought debugging process, the above comment is spectacular and fixes my problem that is saving using `git difftool <branch1> <branch2>` was saving to a **temporary** location, not the current branch. See Adi's comment

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The command `git difftool branch` works as desired, with one "side" as the currently checked-out branch.